# Nginx proxy pass for muliple node apps

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We are running a multinode application on different ports on a single server. We are trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy to route requests to the different applications, depending on the match of a string in the request URI.

We are using the `location` directive to match that string and route accordingly. If we return some value matching the strings in the location directive, it works fine. But as soon it is used in `proxy_pass` we only see a 402 error. What are we doing wrong?

Our config:

```
server {

                listen 443 ssl;
                listen [::]:443 ssl;
                server_name abc.xyz.co;
                include snippets/ssl-qaapp.xyz.co.conf;
                include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
                add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload; always';

location / 

{
        root /var/www/html/abc;
}

location ~ 3000 
{
#       proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000;
        return 403;
        }
location ~ 3001 
{
#       proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3001;
        return 502;
       }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your configuration.

Comment: if i comment proxy_pass it works. If i comment return it through 402 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your configuration you can only reach your location if you query exactly https://abc.xyz.co/3000 or https://abc.xyz.co/3001.

When you are entering your matching location, nginx will proxy your request to your backend (=upstream) on exactly one of the URL https://127.0.0.1:3000 or https://127.0.0.1:3001.
If you get an HTTP answer code 402 it means that the corresponding backend returns it.

In other word, if you query https://abc.xyz.co/3000 or https://abc.xyz.co/3001 from your nginx server manually using wget or curl you will get the same return code.

Comment: Thanks, nothing wrong with the configuration. Node was replying 402.